# Wordpress + Vagrant : The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, vagrant

I am following [this tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/vagrant-wordpress-test-environment/?nhp=b&utm_expid=3606929-87.FQUx5sKvRhKbhK_8_C59WQ.1) to set up Wordpress with vagrant. But it does not seem to work.

I get the following:

```
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/tmp/tmpJZaDWh/secring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/tmp/tmpJZaDWh/pubring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: /tmp/tmpJZaDWh/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ond\xc5\x99ej Sur?" imported
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: Total number processed: 1
==> default: gpg: 
==> default:               imported: 1
==> default:   (RSA: 1)
```

and then:

```
==> default: E
==> default: : 
==> default: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
==> default: tee: 
==> default: /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: xdebug.scream=1
==> default: xdebug.cli_color=1
==> default: xdebug.show_local_vars=1
==> default: sudo
==> default: : 
==> default: a2enmod: command not found
==> default: sed: can't read /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini: No such file or directory
==> default: sed: can't read /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini: No such file or directory
==> default: sed: can't read /etc/php5/cli/php.ini: No such file or directory
==> default: apache2: unrecognized service
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 26: php: command not found
==> default: mv: 
==> default: cannot stat `composer.phar'
==> default: : No such file or directory
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I do not know what this means, really, or where the problem could lie. Vagrant does work though, I have been able to start up a vagrant box before without errors. It is just in the context of the above mentioned tutorial that I run into problems.

edit:
following the advice here, I have changed my vagrantfile & the install.sh. However, I still get the same error. Here are my modified files:

**Vagrantfile**:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.21"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"

end
```

**install.sh**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

sudo apt-get install -y vim curl python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-readline mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core php5-xdebug

cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
EOF

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/disable_functions = .*/disable_functions = /" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

sudo service apache2 restart

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial is a bit old and for sure contains some outdated information.

## use an up to date box

The precise64 box used in the tutorial has not been updated in the last 2 years, you should use a more recent version of this box, so replace

```
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
```

with a single line

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"
```

vagrant will automatically download the box from atlas

## php repo is outdated

the php repo used in the example has been [deprecated](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5)

> This PPA is going to be DEPRECATED, please use ppa:ondrej/php
>
> If you need other PHP versions use:
>
> ```
>   PHP 5.4: ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
>   PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0: ppa:ondrej/php (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
> ```

so the install.sh script will be

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'

sudo apt-get install -y vim curl python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-readline mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core php5-xdebug

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/disable_functions = .*/disable_functions = /" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

sudo service apache2 restart

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

With this 2 changes, it should already get you in a better state - it will start but as said its pretty old post now and  if you're looking for development you should look to upgrade the stack -

Comment: thanks a lot. I do not understand what exactly to do in the second step though (php repo is outdated)?

Comment: in the `install.sh` script there is `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5` this repo is outdated so you need to replace this with one of the 2 values from the message

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I am still not following, I am an absolute beginner. I have replaced 'sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5' with 'sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php', but it still gives me an error, so I guess I did not understand you correctly there? Which 2 values from the message do you mean?

Comment: I have tried it with both `ppa:ondrej/php` and `ppa:ondrej/php`, but it gives me the same error. To be sure, I have replaced `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5` with `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: really ? weird with oldstable it would work - recreate your VM, run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` to destroy and recreate your VM

Comment: ok with oldstable it now worked. Thank you so much for this. But there are still quite a few red lines showing up in my terminal. But it does put the vagrant box up. Should I worry about the red warnings / errors?

Comment: no the red things say that apache will use the IP as FQN for the server, you can still go and edit http conf if you need but not necessarily, it should be ok for you to start working with. please make sure to accept and/or upvote the answer